# XSLT - transformation only uses first found value and ignore other criteria

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

Hello again my experts of XSLT :)

I`m using Saxon9he to transform XML-Content from one file to another. 
For this, the jar file receive some search values.

```
<IBAN> and <IntrBkSttlmAmt>
```

The XSLT must catch

```
<StsId>ID-001</StsId>
```

and write the result to the output file.

Everything works (thanks for your help) until the Input file got identical

```
<IBAN>DE13702203005003963537</IBAN>
```

If i using the example input file & search for

```
<IBAN>DE13702203005003963537</IBAN>
```

and

```
<IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">2.00</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
```

The result is:

```
<OrgnlTxId>ID-001</OrgnlTxId>
<IBAN>DE13702203005003963537</IBAN>
<IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">2.00</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
```

As you can see it catches always the content from the first transaction which has the IBAN. It ignores the search amount value.

Example-Input-File: (only snip of the relevant content)

```
        <TxInfAndSts>
        <StsId>ID-001</StsId>
        <OrgnlInstrId>2017-11-07-B2B0819300000</OrgnlInstrId>
        <OrgnlEndToEndId>NotProvided</OrgnlEndToEndId>
        <OrgnlTxId>TSTBDEM0XXX20171107TXIDB2B081930000</OrgnlTxId>
        <TxSts>RJCT</TxSts>
        <StsRsnInf>
            <Orgtr>
                <Id>
                    <OrgId>
                        <BICOrBEI>TSTBDEMUXXX</BICOrBEI>
                    </OrgId>
                </Id>
            </Orgtr>
            <Rsn>
                <Cd>AG01</Cd>
            </Rsn>
        </StsRsnInf>
        <OrgnlTxRef>
            <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">1</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
            <IntrBkSttlmDt>2017-11-08</IntrBkSttlmDt>
            <ReqdColltnDt>2017-11-08</ReqdColltnDt>
            <CdtrSchmeId>
                <Id>
                    <PrvtId>
                        <Othr>
                            <Id>DE98ZZZ09999999999</Id>
                            <SchmeNm>
                                <Prtry>SEPA</Prtry>
                            </SchmeNm>
                        </Othr>
                    </PrvtId>
                </Id>
            </CdtrSchmeId>
            <SttlmInf>
                <SttlmMtd>CLRG</SttlmMtd>
                <ClrSys>
                    <Prtry>SCL</Prtry>
                </ClrSys>
            </SttlmInf>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <SvcLvl>
                    <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
                </SvcLvl>
                <LclInstrm>
                    <Cd>B2B</Cd>
                </LclInstrm>
                <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
            </PmtTpInf>
            <MndtRltdInf>
                <MndtId>Freierfunden123</MndtId>
                <DtOfSgntr>2017-10-25</DtOfSgntr>
                <AmdmntInd>true</AmdmntInd>
                <AmdmntInfDtls>
                    <OrgnlCdtrSchmeId>
                        <Nm>FIRMA X</Nm>
                        <Id>
                            <PrvtId>
                                <Othr>
                                    <Id>DE98ZZZ09999999999</Id>
                                    <SchmeNm>
                                        <Prtry>SEPA</Prtry>
                                    </SchmeNm>
                                </Othr>
                            </PrvtId>
                        </Id>
                    </OrgnlCdtrSchmeId>
                </AmdmntInfDtls>
            </MndtRltdInf>
            <RmtInf>
                <Ustrd>Test 1</Ustrd>
            </RmtInf>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>THSTAHL</Nm>
            </Dbtr>
            <DbtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <IBAN>DE13702203005003963537</IBAN>
                </Id>
            </DbtrAcct>
            <DbtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <BIC>TSTBDEMUXXX</BIC>
                </FinInstnId>
            </DbtrAgt>
            <CdtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <BIC>HYVEDEMMXXX</BIC>
                </FinInstnId>
            </CdtrAgt>
            <Cdtr>
                <Nm>FIRMA X</Nm>
            </Cdtr>
            <CdtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <IBAN>DE39700202704320253727</IBAN>
                </Id>
            </CdtrAcct>
        </OrgnlTxRef>
    </TxInfAndSts>
    <TxInfAndSts>

        <StsId>ID-002</StsId>
        <OrgnlInstrId>2017-11-07-B2B1058300002</OrgnlInstrId>
        <OrgnlEndToEndId>0</OrgnlEndToEndId>
        <OrgnlTxId>TSTBDEM0XXX20171107TXIDB2B105830002</OrgnlTxId>
        <TxSts>RJCT</TxSts>
        <StsRsnInf>
            <Orgtr>
                <Id>
                    <OrgId>
                        <BICOrBEI>TSTBDEMUXXX</BICOrBEI>
                    </OrgId>
                </Id>
            </Orgtr>
            <Rsn>
                <Cd>AG01</Cd>
            </Rsn>
        </StsRsnInf>
        <OrgnlTxRef>
            <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">2</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
            <IntrBkSttlmDt>2017-11-08</IntrBkSttlmDt>
            <ReqdColltnDt>2017-11-08</ReqdColltnDt>
            <CdtrSchmeId>
                <Id>
                    <PrvtId>
                        <Othr>
                            <Id>DE98ZZZ09999999999</Id>
                            <SchmeNm>
                                <Prtry>SEPA</Prtry>
                            </SchmeNm>
                        </Othr>
                    </PrvtId>
                </Id>
            </CdtrSchmeId>
            <SttlmInf>
                <SttlmMtd>CLRG</SttlmMtd>
                <ClrSys>
                    <Prtry>SCL</Prtry>
                </ClrSys>
            </SttlmInf>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <SvcLvl>
                    <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
                </SvcLvl>
                <LclInstrm>
                    <Cd>B2B</Cd>
                </LclInstrm>
                <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
            </PmtTpInf>
            <MndtRltdInf>
                <MndtId>Freierfunden123</MndtId>
                <DtOfSgntr>2017-10-25</DtOfSgntr>
                <AmdmntInd>true</AmdmntInd>
                <AmdmntInfDtls>
                    <OrgnlCdtrSchmeId>
                        <Nm>FIRMA X</Nm>
                        <Id>
                            <PrvtId>
                                <Othr>
                                    <Id>DE98ZZZ09999999999</Id>
                                    <SchmeNm>
                                        <Prtry>SEPA</Prtry>
                                    </SchmeNm>
                                </Othr>
                            </PrvtId>
                        </Id>
                    </OrgnlCdtrSchmeId>
                </AmdmntInfDtls>
            </MndtRltdInf>
            <RmtInf>
                <Ustrd>Test 2</Ustrd>
            </RmtInf>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>THSTAHL</Nm>
            </Dbtr>
            <DbtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <IBAN>DE13702203005003963537</IBAN>
                </Id>
            </DbtrAcct>
            <DbtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <BIC>TSTBDEMUXXX</BIC>
                </FinInstnId>
            </DbtrAgt>
            <CdtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <BIC>HYVEDEMMXXX</BIC>
                </FinInstnId>
            </CdtrAgt>
            <Cdtr>
                <Nm>FIRMA X</Nm>
            </Cdtr>
            <CdtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <IBAN>DE39700202704320253727</IBAN>
                </Id>
            </CdtrAcct>
        </OrgnlTxRef>
    </TxInfAndSts>
```

Here are some (bigger) XSLT-Snip:

```
<xsl:variable name="all_TxInf_Nodes" select="SCLSDD:BBkIDFBlkDirDeb/SCLSDD:FIToFIPmtStsRpt/myTxNS:TxInfAndSts"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$all_TxInf_Nodes">
                    <xsl:if test="(position()&lt;=number($_rjct_anzahl) and position()&lt;3)">
                        <TxInfAndSts xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                            <StsId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(),'[Y0001][M01][D01]P[H01][m01]')"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                            </StsId>
                            <OrgnlEndToEndId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                <xsl:value-of select="myTxNS:OrgnlEndToEndId"/>
                            </OrgnlEndToEndId>
                            <OrgnlTxId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                <xsl:value-of select="myTxNS:StsId"/>
                            </OrgnlTxId>
                            <TxSts xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">RJCT</TxSts>
                            <StsRsnInf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                <Orgtr>
                                    <Id>
                                        <OrgId>
                                            <BICOrBEI>MARKDEF0</BICOrBEI>
                                        </OrgId>
                                    </Id>
                                </Orgtr>
                                <Rsn>
                                    <Cd>ED05</Cd>
                                </Rsn>
                            </StsRsnInf>
                            <OrgnlTxRef>
                                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                                    <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$_find_amount"/>
                                    </IntrBkSttlmAmt>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:IntrBkSttlmDt">
                                        <IntrBkSttlmDt>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                        </IntrBkSttlmDt>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                    <DbtrAgt>
                                        <FinInstnId>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:DbtrAgt/myTxNS:FinInstnId/myTxNS:BIC">
                                                <BIC>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                                </BIC>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </FinInstnId>
                                    </DbtrAgt>
                                    <CdtrAgt>
                                        <FinInstnId>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:CdtrAgt/myTxNS:FinInstnId/myTxNS:BIC">
                                                <BIC>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                                </BIC>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </FinInstnId>
                                    </CdtrAgt>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="(position()&lt;=number($_rjct_anzahl) and position()=2)">
                                    <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$_find_amount2"/>
                                    </IntrBkSttlmAmt>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:IntrBkSttlmDt">
                                        <IntrBkSttlmDt>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                        </IntrBkSttlmDt>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                    <DbtrAgt>
                                        <FinInstnId>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:DbtrAgt/myTxNS:FinInstnId/myTxNS:BIC">
                                                <BIC>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                                </BIC>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </FinInstnId>
                                    </DbtrAgt>
                                    <CdtrAgt>
                                        <FinInstnId>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:CdtrAgt/myTxNS:FinInstnId/myTxNS:BIC">
                                                <BIC>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                                </BIC>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </FinInstnId>
                                    </CdtrAgt>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </OrgnlTxRef>
                        </TxInfAndSts>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

and the parameter for Saxon:

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -s:"Input.xml" -xsl:transform.xslt -o:output.xml _GrpSts=PART _find_iban=DE13702203005003963537 _find_amount=2.00
```

Comment: I guess we need to see the parts of the XSLT that uses those parameters to select nodes.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the 3 lines of code that you've shown us. The bug is somewhere in the code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: That parameter `_find_amount` is used once in `<xsl:value-of select="$_find_amount"/>` to output the value, it is not compared to anything in the input. So in what way is "the search amount value" ignored? If you simply output it somewhere I don't understand where/how you would want it to be used to select different input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working solution:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$all_TxInf_Nodes">
                    <xsl:if test="$_GrpSts = 'PART'">
                        <xsl:variable name="betrag" select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:IntrBkSttlmAmt"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="iban" select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:DbtrAcct/myTxNS:Id/myTxNS:IBAN"/>
                        <xsl:if test="(number($betrag)=number($_find_amount) and $iban=$_find_iban)">
                            <TxInfAndSts xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                <StsId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(),'[Y0001][M01][D01]P[H01][m01]')"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                                </StsId>
                                <OrgnlEndToEndId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="myTxNS:OrgnlEndToEndId"/>
                                </OrgnlEndToEndId>
                                <OrgnlTxId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="myTxNS:StsId"/>
                                </OrgnlTxId>
                                <TxSts xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">RJCT</TxSts>
                                <StsRsnInf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                    <Orgtr>
                                        <Id>
                                            <OrgId>
                                                <BICOrBEI>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="$send_inst"/>
                                                </BICOrBEI>
                                            </OrgId>
                                        </Id>
                                    </Orgtr>
                                    <Rsn>
                                        <Cd>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$rsf_rjct_reason"/>
                                        </Cd>
                                    </Rsn>
                                </StsRsnInf>
                                <OrgnlTxRef>
                                    <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$_find_amount"/>
                                    </IntrBkSttlmAmt>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:IntrBkSttlmDt">
                                        <IntrBkSttlmDt>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                        </IntrBkSttlmDt>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                    <DbtrAgt>
                                        <FinInstnId>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:DbtrAgt/myTxNS:FinInstnId/myTxNS:BIC">
                                                <BIC>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                                </BIC>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </FinInstnId>
                                    </DbtrAgt>
                                    <CdtrAgt>
                                        <FinInstnId>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:CdtrAgt/myTxNS:FinInstnId/myTxNS:BIC">
                                                <BIC>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                                </BIC>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </FinInstnId>
                                    </CdtrAgt>
                                </OrgnlTxRef>
                            </TxInfAndSts>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="(number($betrag)=number($_find_amount2) and $iban=$_find_iban2)">
                            <TxInfAndSts xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                <StsId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(),'[Y0001][M01][D01]P[H01][m01]')"/>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                                </StsId>
                                <OrgnlEndToEndId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="myTxNS:OrgnlEndToEndId"/>
                                </OrgnlEndToEndId>
                                <OrgnlTxId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="myTxNS:StsId"/>
                                </OrgnlTxId>
                                <TxSts xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">RJCT</TxSts>
                                <StsRsnInf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                    <Orgtr>
                                        <Id>
                                            <OrgId>
                                                <BICOrBEI>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="$send_inst"/>
                                                </BICOrBEI>
                                            </OrgId>
                                        </Id>
                                    </Orgtr>
                                    <Rsn>
                                        <Cd>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$rsf_rjct_reason"/>
                                        </Cd>
                                    </Rsn>
                                </StsRsnInf>
                                <OrgnlTxRef>
                                    <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="EUR">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$_find_amount2"/>
                                    </IntrBkSttlmAmt>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:IntrBkSttlmDt">
                                        <IntrBkSttlmDt>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                        </IntrBkSttlmDt>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                    <DbtrAgt>
                                        <FinInstnId>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:DbtrAgt/myTxNS:FinInstnId/myTxNS:BIC">
                                                <BIC>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                                </BIC>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </FinInstnId>
                                    </DbtrAgt>
                                    <CdtrAgt>
                                        <FinInstnId>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:CdtrAgt/myTxNS:FinInstnId/myTxNS:BIC">
                                                <BIC>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                                </BIC>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </FinInstnId>
                                    </CdtrAgt>
                                </OrgnlTxRef>
                            </TxInfAndSts>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="$_GrpSts = 'RJCT'">
                        <TxInfAndSts xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                            <StsId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(),'[Y0001][M01][D01]P[H01][m01]')"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                            </StsId>
                            <OrgnlEndToEndId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                <xsl:value-of select="myTxNS:OrgnlEndToEndId"/>
                            </OrgnlEndToEndId>
                            <OrgnlTxId xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                <xsl:value-of select="myTxNS:StsId"/>
                            </OrgnlTxId>
                            <TxSts xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">RJCT</TxSts>
                            <StsRsnInf xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL">
                                <Orgtr>
                                    <Id>
                                        <OrgId>
                                            <BICOrBEI>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="$send_inst"/>
                                            </BICOrBEI>
                                        </OrgId>
                                    </Id>
                                </Orgtr>
                                <Rsn>
                                    <Cd>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$rsf_rjct_reason"/>
                                    </Cd>
                                </Rsn>
                            </StsRsnInf>
                            <OrgnlTxRef>
                                <xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:IntrBkSttlmAmt">
                                    <IntrBkSttlmAmt xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:sdd:pacs.002.001.03SCL" Ccy="EUR">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </IntrBkSttlmAmt>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:IntrBkSttlmDt">
                                    <IntrBkSttlmDt>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </IntrBkSttlmDt>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <DbtrAgt>
                                    <FinInstnId>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:DbtrAgt/myTxNS:FinInstnId/myTxNS:BIC">
                                            <BIC>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                            </BIC>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </FinInstnId>
                                </DbtrAgt>
                                <CdtrAgt>
                                    <FinInstnId>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="myTxNS:OrgnlTxRef/myTxNS:CdtrAgt/myTxNS:FinInstnId/myTxNS:BIC">
                                            <BIC>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                            </BIC>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </FinInstnId>
                                </CdtrAgt>
                            </OrgnlTxRef>
                        </TxInfAndSts>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
```